# What is the difference between the below two sh scripts

Tags: shell

This is not a homework.

I'm new to shell script and learning on my own.

Please help me in differentiating the below two scripts

```
MY_NAME=$(echo "$FILELIST" | grep $MY_NAME ) 
MY_NAME=$(ls -1 $MY_NAME)
```

Comment: They do two completely different things. Are you familiar with the `ls`, `grep`, and `echo` commands?

Comment: just copy/paste "atoms" from each to the command-line, working from inside to out, i.e. copy paste `echo "$FILELIST" | grep $MY_NAME` . What does that produce? But... oops, $FILELIST and $MY_NAME are variables. Where are values assigned? You need some thing like `MY_NAME="Oracle Nerd" ; FILELIST="file1 file2 file3"`. Learn to use `set -vx` to see line of code that will be executed (with $VAR_NAMES still showing), followed by a line with a `+` at front that shows the values substituted from VAR_NAMES. This is the command that actually gets executed. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grep command will display only the matching lines while ls -l will list all the files in directory.